# How do I edit the header of an Expander control in WinUI 3?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

When I edit properties of the Expander control, the effects seem to only apply to the content of the Expander, rather than the header.

E.g. if I set the BorderBrush as black and the Background as aquamarine, those properties only apply to the content:

```xml
<Expander Header="Expander" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Aquamarine">
   <TextBlock Text="Here is some text"/>
</Expander>
```

[See what the above code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smtN1.png)

I know I can use this syntax:

```xml
<Expander>
   <Expander.Header>
      <!--XAML content here-->
   </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

and put XAML content inside the header. So I tried putting a StackPanel in there, and editing the border and background on that—but it only applied to a small portion of the Expander header, and didn't cover the drop down caret, for example.

How do I change properties of the header?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the default style but this might be easier:

```xml
<Border
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Background="SkyBlue"
    BorderBrush="HotPink"
    BorderThickness="1"
    CornerRadius="{StaticResource ControlCornerRadius}">
    <Expander
        Content="CONTENT"
        Header="HEADER" />
</Border>
```

You just need to set the `Border`'s properties.